# Find intersection multiplicities

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, affine-geometry

Let curves $A$ and $B$ be defined by $x^2-3x+y^2=0$ and $x^2-6x+10y^2=0$. Find the intersection multiplicities of all points of intersection of $A$ and $B$.

If we let $f=x^2-3x+y^2$ and $g=x^2-6x+10y^2$ we find that $<f,g>=<x,y^2>$. Then my book says that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^2,O}/<x,y^2>$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C<1,y>$. How do they know this? Thanks

Comment: It is not true that the ideal generated by $f,g$ is $\langle x,y^2 \rangle$. It is true in the completion at the maximal ideal, however. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $<f,g>=<x^2-3x+y^2,x-3y^2>$ so that $\mathbb C[x,y]/<f,g>\cong \mathbb C[y]/<9y^4-8y^2>=\mathbb C[y]/<y^2(9y^2-8)>$ .

Localizing at the origin $<x,y>$, we get: $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^2,O}/<f,g>=(\mathbb C[x,y])_{<x,y>}/<f,g>\cong (\mathbb C[y])_{<y>}/<y^2(9y^2-8)> $$ $$=(\mathbb C[y])_{<y>}/<y^2>=(\mathbb C[y]/<y^2>)_{<y>}=\mathbb C[y]/<y^2>=\mathbb C\overline 1\oplus \mathbb C\overline y$$  just as your book says.

[I have used that that taking quotients and localizing commute, that $9y^2-8$ is invertible in the local ring $(\mathbb C[y])_{<y>}$ and at the end that localizing the already local ring $\mathbb C[y]/<y^2>$ at its maximal ideal $<y>$ does not change that ring]

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg Thanks. How did you obtain the isomorphism $\mathbb C[x,y]/<f,g>\cong \mathbb C[y]/<9y^4-8y^2>$?

Comment: By replacing $x$ everywhere by $3y^2$, since $x-3y^2=0$ in the quotient $\mathbb C[x,y]/<f,g>=\mathbb C[x,y]/<x^2-3x+y^2,x-3y^2>$ : everything in the denominator becomes zero in the quotient.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Ok, how do I find the dimension of $\mathbb C[y]/<y^2>$? I'm not quite not sure what you mean by $\mathbb C\overline 1$

Comment: Dear user, $\overline 1$ is the class of $1\in \mathbb C$. You seem to have gaps in elementary algebra: I recommend you review the notion of  quotient ring before attacking algebraic geometry.